# Can't display KML-Layer in Google Maps API

Tags: google-maps, gps, kml

I've been struggling days to get my KML-File working on a Google Maps API. I originally downloaded a GPX-File and made it to .kml to use it on my Maps.

Here's the HTML code:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
function initialize()
{
var mapProp = {
  center: new google.maps.LatLng(47.2769,8.650017),
  zoom:9,
  panControl:true,
  zoomControl:false,
  mapTypeControl:true,
  scaleControl:false,
  streetViewControl:false,
  overviewMapControl:false,
  rotateControl:false, 
  mapTypeId:google.maps.MapTypeId.HYBRID
  };
var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("map-canvas"), mapProp);
var ctaLayer = new google.maps.KmlLayer({

    url: 'kml/route.kml'

  });
ctaLayer.setMap(map);
}
google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, 'load', initialize);
</script>
```

What seems to be the problem? The Map gets displayed, but the Layer with KML-information does not appear. Does it have to do with a connection error to Google? My Firebug Console keeps reporting me network errors like:

> "NetworkError: 407 authenticationrequired - https://maps.gstatic.com/intl/de_de/mapfiles/api-3/15/0/main.js"

BTW The KML File seems to be OK. I uploaded it on Google Maps and it does work.

Does anyone know a better solution to get my GPX cyclingcourse displayed on Google Maps?

Comment: What is the public URL of your KML?

Comment: Your wrote: `BTW The KML File seems to be OK. I uploaded it on Google Maps and it does work.` are you using that same URL to load the KmlLayer? What [status](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/reference#KmlLayerStatus) does the KmlLayer return?

Answer (score -1):

You should host your kml file somewhere. 
https://developers.google.com/kml/articles/pagesforkml?hl=en